# Incremental dynamic on-disk disjoint sets (incremental on-disk dynamic forest)

Tags: union-find

### Problem statement

I am looking for an algorithm to maintain a very large number of disjoint sets under node and edge additions. Due to the data size, keeping everything in memory is not feasible, so the algorithm needs to work efficiently with SSD storage.

Ideally, the algorithm should:

- support `link(v1, v2)` operation which either merges two sets or does nothing if `v1` and `v2` already belong to the same set. If either `v1` or `v2` did not exist prior to link operation, the new vertex(es) should be added to a set
- support `get_set(v)` operation which will return all elements in a set
- be IO efficient in terms of SSD access
- allow concurrent `link` and `get_set` operations

Some notes:

- only edge additions are allowed, no removals
- consecutive `link` operations `1..N` operate on a small number of disjoint sets `K`, `K << N`

### Why I need such an algorithm

There is a stream of events (~100M of events per day) in which each event may link to zero or several "parent" events. When a new event arrives, I need to run some aggregations on a graph that this event belongs to. Events are generated by a set of services, so this is basically a distributed tracing problem.

Comment: What approaches have you considered?  What's wrong with the standard Union-Find data structure?

Comment: @D.W. I have considered the standard Union-Find, but as far as I know it is optimized for keeping the whole structure in main memory, and in my case it is not feasible. I am not aware of an on-disk io-efficient Union-Find data structure.

Comment: Please provide further clarification on in what sense it is not feasible.  What are the specific requirements and metrics that standard Union-Find does not meet?  Have you implemented it and measured it?  Can you be more specific about in what way it fails to meet your requirements?  What exactly counts as "io-efficient" in this context?

Comment: Is it the get_set operation that's the problem?  Regular union-find does not support that.   What's the proportion of operations that are link vs get_set?

Comment: Sorry @D.W. I'm not very good at algorithms so I may be mistaken, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @D.W. As I understand it, regular union-find datastructure is supposed to be kept in RAM. Due to the size of my dataset, this is not feasible as data would require terabytes of RAM. I figured that naively keeping everything on disk would be painfully slow, but I admit I didn't implemented this (I'm not every sure how this implementation would look like). As for the get_set -- it needs to be executed at least once per every set, possibly more. As for the numbers, as I said in OP post there will be 100M events (=100M link operations) per day, and approx. 4-6M get_set operations.

Comment: Most sets are under 50 elements, but some outliers are up to 100K elements.

Comment: There's nothing about the Union-Find data structure that requires it be kept in memory.  You can replace each pointer with an address on disk.